# Regarding Express route adding a unknown variable to GET request, nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have created an app using MEAN Stack..

it works properly with both localhost and intranet..
both accesible at 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/#/home

in order to access it through internet:

```
        mapping is done say.. 
        www.abc.com/test/project/

       /project/ is mapped to my ip(172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000)
```

so when when www.abc.com/test/project/#/home is called 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/#/home

but what happens is everytime GET request from express-route
gets an additional /project/ is appennded

that is,rather than calling GET /css/style.css
                             it calls GET /project/css/style.css

this happens only when i try to acces from internet where /project/ is mapped to http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/#/home

Comment: Who is doing the mapping? Please post the configuration for that as well.

Comment: it done by network admin,i am not sure about that. he actually maps the data comming from the server to my ip .
/project/ is mapped to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000